# Converting xml.etree.ElementTree to string raises "TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable"

Tags: python, typeerror, elementtree

I have a simple XML element created with [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) in Python 3.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree
person = ElementTree.Element("Person", Name="John", Age=18)
```

I can use [`Element.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.get) to access individual attributes from my element without any issues.

```
name = person.get("Name")
age = person.get("Age")
print(name + " is " + str(age) + " years old.")
# output: "John is 18 years old"
```

However, if I try to convert my element to a string with [`.tostring()`](https://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring), I get an error "*TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable*".

```
print(ElementTree.tostring(person))  # TypeError
```

**Why can't I use `.tostring()` on an `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` with an integer attribute?**

---

Full code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

person = ElementTree.Element("Person", Name="John", Age=18)
print(ElementTree.tostring(person))  # TypeError
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\svascellar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1079, in _escape_attrib
    if "&" in text:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/svascellar/.PyCharmCE2017.3/config/scratches/scratch_13.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(ElementTree.tostring(person))
  File "C:\Users\svascellar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1135, in tostring
    short_empty_elements=short_empty_elements)
  File "C:\Users\svascellar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 776, in write
    short_empty_elements=short_empty_elements)
  File "C:\Users\svascellar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 933, in _serialize_xml
    v = _escape_attrib(v)
  File "C:\Users\svascellar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1102, in _escape_attrib
    _raise_serialization_error(text)
  File "C:\Users\svascellar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1057, in _raise_serialization_error
    "cannot serialize %r (type %s)" % (text, type(text).__name__)
TypeError: cannot serialize 18 (type int)
```

Comment: lxml is stricter than ElementTree and doesn't even let you create the document ("TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'int'"). This makes sense, since XML attribute values are strings (as John Gordon points out).

Comment: Related: [Can xml.etree.ElementTree.write() integer values for a given Element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19534288/3357935)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though `Age` is intended to be a numeric value, xml attribute values should be quoted strings:

```
person = ElementTree.Element("Person", Name="John", Age="18")
```

Alternatively, if the data was stored as a variable, convert it to a string with `str()`

```
age = 18
person = ElementTree.Element("Person", Name="John", Age=str(age))
```